# Time picker scroll-snap issue

Tags: reactjs, timepicker, scroll-snap

I am trying to re-create the time picker used in the Samsung Galaxy devices' Clock(Alarm) app.

So far, I made good progress, but I have one issue.

When I scroll sometimes(most of the time) 1 hour/minute is skipped. Ex -> 00 => scroll => 02(should be - 01).

Also, I want to make it draggable(swipe/touch behavior) but with the mouse.

This is my component - https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-platform-xs7tpd?file=/src/AlarmPicker.tsx

The expected behavior is when you scroll with the mouse the values to scroll one by one. Or when you drag(grab) one value to be able to scroll them.